# React native routing vs React navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

I'm about to choose whether to use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) or to use [React Router Native](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/guides/philosophy), I thought that React Navigation is better, but then I found some feedbacks like this [react navigation issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2031), ps: [React Router Native](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/guides/philosophy) has similar API to [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy) which seems very simple, I'm still lost! I need an advice

Answer (score 5):

In my experience React Navigation works like a charm. It uses native-alike layouts if you don't wanna create your own, and let you customize them via props as you wish. It also lets you navigate inside functions without the need of redux actions, which i think are a must in React Router.
The main problem of React Navigation is its  documentation, which is pretty lackluster. It has no complex examples, only simple stuff, so you have to lurk a little bit to do some stuff if your app starts getting complex, with a lot of nests.
Even so, the only hard to solve problem i really had with React Navigation was when i had a Stack Navigator (2nd) inside a Drawer Navigator which was nested inside a main Stack Navigator (1st), which back then wouldn't let me change the main header from within the 2nd Stack Navigator. This could be worked around by putting the 2nd Stack Navigator directly inside the main one.