# Technical difference between react-router-native and react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-router-native

newbie here at React Native.

`react-router` is a popular library for navigation in web apps. This same library has a package that provides an API for navigation in RN, `react-router-native`. [Docs](https://reactrouter.com/native/guides/quick-start)

After [reading](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/pitch) `react-navigation`'s pitch and anti-pitch, I am curious to understand the difference in the internal working of the two.

There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662744/react-native-routing-vs-react-navigation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075444/which-one-to-choose-react-native-router-flux-or-react-router-native-or-react-nav), but the answers are opinionated and unable to point out the differences of working between the two.

Requesting any helpful information about the two libraries here! Any particular use case where one performed better over the other would also help!

Comment: does anyone know the answer for this?